# Haskell loop until a key is pressed

Tags: haskell

I would like to run a program every `n` second and refresh the screen(certain lines) until i press the `q` key. How to achieve this?

I have checked the `ansi-terminal` package for refreshing certain part of the screen. I'm guessing that I should use `haskeline` to get the loop and user key press. Am I correct ?

If yes I can't find the function in haskeline.

Comment: You probably need two threads. One runs a sleep-refresh loop, one waits for input and exits (use `getInputChar` from haskeline.

Comment: How do I run two threads ? Another library function for this ?

Comment: [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/pcph/) by Simon Marlow has an example of using forkIO to bail out of a program early on user input. See "A Simple Example: Reminders" in Chapter 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty simply with nothing but the `IO` Monad with `threadDelay` from `Control.Concurrent`.

```
import Control.Concurrent

refreshInterval :: Int
refreshInterval = 10000 -- in microseconds

refreshAction :: IO ()
refreshAction = undefined

main :: IO ()
main = do refreshAction
          threadDelay refreshInterval
          main
```

With this structure, you can now incorporate a keyboard quit via any library that gives you keyboard input. For example, with haskeline, you can read input with `getInputChar`, compare it to your quit character, and exit if necessary. But doing it directly this way will leave you unable to read input while the thread sleeps with `threadDelay`. If your input library buffers reads, this might be ok -- the quit/break action will simply occur when the program gets around to checking for input. If you need more than that, you can either roll your own solution via `forkIO` as suggested in the comments, or move to a library that handles this sort of thing a bit better.

As an interesting side note, this is pretty easily solved within my OpenCV library using the parts of the library that wrap OpenCV's HighGUI functionality. I don't necessarily recommend pulling in that dependency just for this functionality, but it does technically solve your problem. I'll add that to this answer if anyone is interested.